# Why my element is triggering on a classname

Tags: google-analytics-4

Im new to GA4, and I have been able to fire up tags on class elements.
But I dont understand why this doesn't fire?

I have tested this with "strip-section" so it's nothing to do with missing a letter.

Any advise is appreciated

[image]

[image]

The tag to fire when clicked on the class

Answer (score 1):

There are two things we need to fix here.

1. The `Click Element` need to use `match css selector`. Although contains looks no problem at first place. But the `Click Element` can only use the `match css selector` designed by Google Tag Manager.
2. We need to match the class name at full: like
   div.stips-section.stips-money-tips

Comment: many thanks for your response, i have tried this but it's still the same. I'm unable yto share an image but i've used the match css seletor and added the div, but its still not firing

Comment: div#stips-container > div.stips-section.stips-money-tips > div.stips-header this fixes the issue, but could anyone tell me why? does an id need to be involved?

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see that until now. From the Preview: the last element is ` div.stips-header` . This mean the GTM detect this click action is happen on this element. So our previous selector is not right because it is the parent of the click element

Comment: it could be right if you add a star to the selector to indicate that you wanna select all the children.

Comment: Appreciate your help thanks you. this has worked :)